# GWT SafeHTML, XSS & Best Practices

Tags: security, gwt, xss, owasp

The good people of OWASP emphasize that you MUST use the escape syntax for the part of the HTML document you’re putting untrusted data into (body, attribute, JavaScript, CSS, or URL). See [OWASP - XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). Their API (developed by the ESAPI team) subsequently caters for this having encoders for each context:

`ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML("input");
ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTMLAttribute("input");
ESAPI.encoder().encodeForJavaScript("input");
ESAPI.encoder().encodeForCSS("input");
ESAPI.encoder().encodeForURL("input");`

Subsequently this allows the developer to cater for [DOM-based XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) .

So my question is how does GWT's safehtml package cater for this or does it merely focus on HTML encoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`SafeHtmlTemplates`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/safehtml/client/SafeHtmlTemplates.html) will do it (client-side only though, as it relies on a GWT generator). It'll parse the HTML fragment using a "tag soup" parser, that will infer the context and either log a warning or throw if the argument cannot be used in this context (for instance, it prevents all use of placeholders in script context). This is still in flux though (`SafeUri` is still in review and [`SafeStyles`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/safecss/shared/SafeStyles.html) is still severely limited) but it'll be there in due time (should be in GWT 2.4 I think).

Otherwise:

- [`SafeHtmlUtils`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/SafeHtmlUtils.html)'s will escape all of `<`, `>`, `&`, `'` and `"` so the result is safe for "HTML" and "HTML attribute" contexts
- `SafeHtmlBuilder`'s various append methods will just call `SafeHtmlUtils` under the hood
- [`UriUtils`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/UriUtils.html) provides tools to scrub unsafe URIs (you'll still need a `SafeHtmlUtils` pass or equivalent afterwards if you're building an HTML string –vs. using the value directly for an image's source or anchor's href–).
- `SafeStyles` doesn't provide anything specific in itself, but `SafeHtmlTemplates` will only allow it at the beginning of a CSS context, and will log a warning if you try to put anything else in a CSS context. `SafeStylesBuilder` is expected to be extended with *type-safe* methods, to help build *well-formed* CSS.
- [I've been working](http://gwt-code-reviews.appspot.com/1380806/) on a `SafeUri` interface, similar to `SafeStyles` but in a URL context. In due time, `SafeHtmlTemplates` will only allow a `SafeUri` or a `String` as the *full value* of a URL attribute, passing the `String` through `UriUtils` to make sure it's safe.

In brief, I think the answer to your question is: yes, GWT's safehtml package cater for this; but you'll probably have to always use the latest version of GWT (at least for the coming year) to be *safe*.

Comment: So basically the SafeHTMLTemplates is what I would use when dealing with contexts other than HTML, but you recommend to not rely on it to safely encode URL and styles in GWT 2.3? And lastly is DOM-based XSS something to consider in GWT as we do have the ability to directly set DOM element's inner html?

Comment: There's no magic, everything that SafeHtmlTemplates does you can do yourself; but SafeHtmlTemplates automates a number of checks that you'd have had to do by inspecting your code. For now (GWT 2.3), it's not advanced enough to check CSS (I'm not sure it'll ever do, what's planned is to give you a tool to help you *build* safe CSS). As for URLs, it'll call `UriUtils.sanitizeUri` so you'll be safe, but there are a few safe URIs that it'll scrub (e.g. a `data:`  URI that you *know* is safe), and a few corner cases that it'll leave as-is despite being unsafe (see the `SafeUri` code review).

Comment: Finally: DOM-based CSS is definitely something to worry about in GWT, and that's why `SafeHtml` and friends have been added in the first place. Whenever you can set the `innerHTML` of an element, try to build it using `SafeHtml` tools. It won't ever replace auditing your code, but it should greatly help in doing so.