# GWT HTML Widget XSS security

Tags: html, security, gwt, xss

Might be a noobish question (most likely) but according to the official developer documents GWT's HTML widget is not XSS safe and one must exercise caution when embedding custom HTML/Script text.

So i guess my question is, why does this:

```
HTML testLabel = new HTML("dada<script type='text/javascript'>document.write('<b>Hello World</b>');</script>");
```

Not show a javascript popup? If somehow, GWT's HTML widget does protect from XSS attacks then in what types of situations does it not (so i can know what to expect)?

Comment: see similar post here: [SafeHTml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177329/gwt-safehtml-xss-best-practices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWT documentation contains few [articles](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecurity) about security (including dealing with XSS using [SafeHtml](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml)).

Your example doesn't work because scripts defined via `innerHTML` doesn't get executed in Chrome/Firefox(i think there were some workaround for IE using `defer` attribute).

But you shouldn't rely on this browser restriction.. So it is better to use SafeHtml and always validate inputs from users.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about this widget in particular, but in general it is worth knowing that XSS vectors come in *many many* flavours. Only a small percentage actually use the `script` tag.

One very important factor is that they are location-dependent. For example, a string that is xss-safe outside any tags, may not be safe inside a tag's attribute value, or within a delimited string that is inside a javascript block.

They can also be browser-dependent, as many exploit 'bugs' in the document parsing model.

To get a sense of the variety of different vectors that can be abused to produce malicious javascript injection, please see these two [cheat](http://html5sec.org/) [sheets](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html)

I also recommend you read the  [prevention cheat sheet at owasp](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Thank you very much, extremelly helpfull language-agnostic resources!